# Inserting data from pandas data frame to Sqlite using Sqlite query

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

grateful for your help.  I'm trying to take a series of cleaned tweets and upload them to a sqlite database.  I can make this work using pandas.DataFrame.to_sql, but ideally I would like to do it via sqlite queries.  When I run this, I get the error:

```
blogs=open("clean_tweet.csv","r").read().decode("ISO-8859-1")
blogs=unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", blogs).encode("ascii", "ignore").lower()

alldata = blogs

tokenizer=RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens=tokenizer.tokenize(alldata)

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')

for token in tokens:
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO unigram_trial (word_trial) VALUES (?)", (str(token), ))

    conn.commit()
```

Using this, I can insert all of the tokens into one single table row, but it will not insert as individual words in individual rows.

Am I missing something?  Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert command with sqlite3 always expects a single row of data. A simple for loop over your tokens list should do:

```
for token in tokens:
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO unigram_trial (word_trial) VALUES (?)", (str(token),))
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is create a function to run it as a DataFrame for every call:

```
def run_query(q):
    with sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite') as conn:
        return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)


# view columns in table (or whatever you want to call with SQL syntax)
query = "SELECT * FROM database"
df = run_query(query)
for i,v in enumerate(query):
    print(i,v)
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I make this work for my INSERT call?  I've tried:                     

# view columns in table (or whatever you want to call with SQL syntax)
query = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO unigram_trial (word_trial) VALUES (WORD)"
df = run_query(query)
for i,v in enumerate(query):
    print(i,v)                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                This returns the same error

Comment: On your end: I am unfamiliar with whether the error might lie with your INSERT query - perhaps try writing a SELECT query?

On my end: I meant to write -
``` for i,v in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(i,v)```